# Swift - Changing variable inside struct?

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm a beginner in Swift and static programming. Going through Big Nerd Ranch Swift book. What I don't understand is why myTown population is changing, but not fredTheZombie.town?  The exercise calls for the town population to never go below zero.  This could happen when the population is less than 10.  How do I change the fredTheZombie.town population variable?

```
struct Town {
    var population = 5422
    var numberOfStoplights = 4

    func printTownDescription() {
        print("Population: \(myTown.population), number of stoplights: \(myTown.numberOfStoplights)")
    }

    mutating func changePopulation(amount: Int) {
        population += amount
    }
}

class Monster {
    var town: Town?
    var name = "Monster"

    func terrorizeTown() {
        if town != nil {
            print("\(name) is terrorizing a town!")
        } else {
            print("\(name) hasn't found a town to terrorize yet...")
        }
    }
}

class Zombie: Monster {
    var walksWithLimp = true

    final override func terrorizeTown() {
        guard town?.population > 0 else {
            return
        }

        if town?.population > 10 {
            super.town!.changePopulation(-10)
        } else {
            super.town!.population = 0
        }

        super.terrorizeTown()
    }

    func changeName(name: String, walksWithLimp: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.walksWithLimp = walksWithLimp
    }
}

var myTown = Town()
myTown.changePopulation(500)
let fredTheZombie = Zombie()
fredTheZombie.town = myTown
fredTheZombie.terrorizeTown()
fredTheZombie.town?.printTownDescription()
fredTheZombie.changeName("Fred the Zombie", walksWithLimp: false)

myTown.changePopulation(-5915)
print(myTown.population)
print(fredTheZombie.town!.population)
fredTheZombie.terrorizeTown()
fredTheZombie.terrorizeTown()
fredTheZombie.town?.printTownDescription()
```

Output:

```
Monster is terrorizing a town!
Population: 5922, number of stoplights: 4
7
5912
Fred the Zombie is terrorizing a town!
Fred the Zombie is terrorizing a town!
Population: 7, number of stoplights: 4
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Town` is a struct, a value type. When assigning a value type to a different variable (e.g. `fredTheZombie.town = myTown`), that value type is copied (meaning that a new `Town` is created with the same values as the original `Town`).

`myTown` and `fredTheZombie.town` are not the same town any more. If you want them to be the same instance, make them a `class` (a reference type).

See more info on [Apple Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) and in [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82).

The biggest problem we have are optional structs. The result of unwrapping an optional struct (using `town!`) is again a copy, a new town. To work around that, you have to:

```
var myTown = super.town!
myTown.changePopulation(-10)
super.town = myTown // assign back
```

Whole example:

```
struct Town {
    var population = 5422
    var numberOfStoplights = 4

    func printTownDescription() {
        // note you have to print "self" here, not "myTown"
        print("Population: \(self.population), number of stoplights: \(self.numberOfStoplights)")
    }

    mutating func changePopulation(amount: Int) {
        population += amount
    }
}

class Monster {
    var town: Town?
    var name = "Monster"

    func terrorizeTown() {
        if town != nil {
            print("\(name) is terrorizing a town!")
        } else {
            print("\(name) hasn't found a town to terrorize yet...")
        }
    }
}

class Zombie: Monster {
    var walksWithLimp = true

    final override func terrorizeTown() {
        guard super.town?.population > 0 else {
            return
        }

        var town = super.town!

        if town.population > 10 {
            town.changePopulation(-10)
        } else {
            town.population = 0
        }

        super.town = town

        super.terrorizeTown()
    }

    func changeName(name: String, walksWithLimp: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.walksWithLimp = walksWithLimp
    }
}
```

In your case there is no need for `town` to be actually optional. You could just pass it to `Monster` in a constructor.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there a way to change fredTheZombie.town without turning it into the same instance (myTown)?

Comment: @ltrainpr You can assign to any of its variables or call a mutating method. However, since `fredTheZombie.town` is an optional, it won't really work because the result of unwrapping is again a copy. The most common way to work with value types is to always create a new instance.

Comment: @ltrainpr Oh, I see your problem now, let me edit the answer.

Comment: Why `super.town = myTown` instead of `fredTheZombie.town = myTown` or will it work either way?  Or wait, does that code go in the Zombie Class?

Comment: @ltrainpr Depends on the context where you are calling that. You cannot use `super.town` outside a method body and you cannot use `fredTheZombie.town` from `func terrorizeTown`.

Comment: I can't get it to work.  When I call `fredTheZombie.town?.printTownDescription()` it prints `myTown.population` which is the wrong instance of the town when I call `print(fredTheZombie.town!.population)`.  I need to know where the code you suggest goes.

Comment: @ltrainpr I didn't see that mistake, I will paste the whole working code.